# “undefined reference to” error when compiling for MinGW

Tags: c++, sdl, raycasting, visual-studio-code, mingw

I tried to move to MinGW to compile my program, since I am trying to use a more recent OpenMP version than the 2.0 one used in Visual Studio.

I was planning on using `#pragma omp target{}` to pass the function for the GPU since it is a rendering part of the code, but now that I am using MinGW, I can't compile my program anymore. I downloaded mingw-17.1 to get the needed headers and libs for sdl2.

[Here is the GitHub page for the engine](https://github.com/andrew-lim/sdl2-raycast/).

[The error I got](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vavHaADvdj9d5grjZ4YlddV_HlfLUyi-/view?usp=sharing):

> GNU C++14 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
> compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3
> warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
> Compiler executable checksum: af09a87986453bf79da3565f33c7648f
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-o''C:\Users\samsung\source\repos\forespend\forespend\forespend.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdGkN4k.o   
> C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6DG7xs.s  
> GNU assembler version 2.28 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.28
> COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
> LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-o'   
> 'C:\Users\samsung\source\repos\forespend\forespend\forespend.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'  
> c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/collect2.exe -plugin   
> c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxKCd8F.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bdynamic -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info -o   
> C:\Users\samsung\source\repos\forespend\forespend\forespend.exe   
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o   
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o -L  
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -L  
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -L  
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../..   
> C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdGkN4k.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtend.o
>
> C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdGkN4k.o: In function 'ZN4Game5resetEv':
>
> C:/Users/samsung/source/repos/forespend/forespend/main.cpp:235: undefined reference to 'al::raycasting::Raycaster::createGrids(int, int, int, int)'
>
> C:/Users/samsung/source/repos/forespend/forespend/main.cpp:236: undefined reference to `g_map'
> ...

Comment: If your original example does not fit in a question here, then it is your responsibility to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example that does fit here. If it's too much text to post, then it's too much text to expect a stranger to trawl through for you for free. Take the time to pull out the relevant details so you can include them front-and-center in your question text. You'll get better answers that way, faster.

Answer (score 2):

SDL2 has specific binaries for compiling with MinGW. On the downloads page, (https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) download the SDL2-devel-2.0.20-mingw.tar.gz.